# What is Qt Creator doing?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, virtualization, parallels

I noticed Qt Creator seems to be doing something, and taking 15% of CPU. What is going on?

This happens while I'm just looking at the screen, not building anything.

Even if I close the file it still keeps on doing that and taking my CPU.

And why that `clangbackend.exe` if project is configured to use Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler?

Also noted under `QtCreator`, `General Messages`

```
Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.
```

Keeps being printed. What might be causing this?

The machine is a vm with 8 core and 8GB of ram running on Parallels on mid 2015 mbp, intel i7 4770HQ 2.2GHz

Perhaps I should add that I store the project source files in a shared folder on macOS side (which is exposed/shared to the Windows vm). On macOS that folder is on iCloud (I guess so its constantly on sync). This setup might be making things worse.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274409/qt-creator-high-cpu-usage-in-editor

Comment: To follow up with @Michael O., I'm guessing you either have a 4 core with Hyperthreading or an 8 core machine.  14.8 is approximately  100% of 1 thread in Windows.

Comment: The clangbackend is for QtCreator to actually understand your code and provide inspection (hovering over a variable shows its type) and completion features, etc.; what is called "IntelliSense" by Microsoft. It is unrelated to the compiler you use for building your project.